# Why does bash "echo [t]" result in "t" not "[t]"

Tags: bash

This happens for the character t, and the value root.  Quite perplexing

```
$ echo [s]
[s]
$ echo [t]
t
$ echo [ t ]
[ t ]
$ echo [root]
t
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Being not a shell habitué (and not willing to become) I found surprising how filename expansion is designed to behave when no matches are found. I'll report the [Bash reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html)

> Bash scans each word for the characters `*`, `?`, and `[`. If one of
>   these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a pattern, and
>   replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of file names matching the
>   pattern. If no matching file names are found:
>
> - if the shell option `nullglob` is disabled, the word is left unchanged
> - if the shell option `nullglob` is set the word is removed
> - If the `failglob` shell option is set, an error message is printed and the command is not executed

The good news is this thing is configurable. The bad one is a script can fail in a number of ways one doesn't expect - at least, I did not, and it took me some time to understand why `echo` behaves the way you posted, just to find that it's because of a combination of weird filenames (who ever wants to name a file `t`?), hidden configuration (`nullglob` disabled, default option but still hidden) and a *harmless* command.

I said *harmless* because this is what you get, for example, when the target is `ls` (a failure because the file is not found):

```
raffaele@Aldebaran:~$ mkdir test
raffaele@Aldebaran:~$ cd test
raffaele@Aldebaran:~/test$ touch t
raffaele@Aldebaran:~/test$ ls [t]
t
raffaele@Aldebaran:~/test$ ls [v]
ls: cannot access [v]: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Other answers were extremely useful and educational but this got to the heart of the matter for me in the shortest and most concise way - the oddity of echoing the unmatched expression and how to control it.

Comment: FWIW (perhaps nothing!) I often put one-off test code in `t.cpp` and build to target `t`!

Answer (score 62):

`[]` denotes a character class, and you have a file named `t` in your current directory.

The following should explain it further:

```
$ ls
$ echo [t]
[t]
$ touch t
$ echo [t]
t
$ echo [root]
t
$ touch r
$ echo [root]
r t
```

---

If you want to echo something within `[]`, escape the `[`:

```
echo \[$var]
```

Observe the difference now:

```
$ echo \[root]
[root]
```

or, as [Glenn Jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) points out, quote it:

```
$ echo '[root]'
[root]
$ echo "[root]"
[root]
```

---

[Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/chap2.html) tells that the following characters are special to the shell depending upon the context:

```
*   ?   [   #   ~   =   %
```

Moreover, following characters must be quoted if they are to represent themselves:

```
|  &  ;  <  >  (  )  $  `  \  "  '  <space>  <tab>  <newline>
```

---

You could also use `printf` to *determine* which characters in a given input need to be escaped if you are not quoting the arguments.  For your example, i.e. `[s]`:

```
$ printf "%q" "[s]"
\[s\]
```

Another example:

```
$ printf "%q" "[0-9]|[a-z]|.*?$|1<2>3|(foo)"
\[0-9\]\|\[a-z\]\|.\*\?\$\|1\<2\>3\|\(foo\)
```

Comment: @glennjackman You're right, I should've added that.  Done that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

`[]` denotes a character class. Simply put, a character class is a way of denoting a set of characters in such a way that **one character** of the set is matched. `[A-Z]` is a very common example — it matches all the alphabets from `A` through `Z`.

Here are the results of the commands in a new directory:

```
$ echo [s]
[s]
$ echo [t]
[t]
$ echo [ t ]
[ t ]
$ echo [root]
[root]
```

As you can see, `echo` displayed them as it is. Why? Read the next section.

### Expansion

Every time you type a command on the Terminal and press the ENTER key, bash performs a lot of operations internally before printing out the results to the shell. The simplest example is the expansion of `*`:

```
$ echo *
evil_plans.txt dir1 dir2
```

Instead of displaying the literal `*` as the output, it printed the contents of the directory. Why did this happen? Because `*` has a special meaning — it is a wildcard, which can match any character of a filename. It is important to note that the `echo` command doesn't actually see the `*` at all — only the expanded result.

There are different kinds of expansions:

- Brace expansion
- Tilde expansion
- Parameter expansion
- Command expansion
- Arithmetic expansion
- Process substitution
- File name expansion

... and probably more. In this case, file name expansion is the relevant type of expansion.

### File name expansion

When you type an `echo` command and press ENTER, bash processes the command and splits it into words. Once that is done, it scans the words for the following characters: `?`, `*` and `[`. All of these are metacharacters and have a special meaning. If bash finds an occurrence of either of these characters, it treats the supplied word as a pattern.

For example, consider the following case:

```
$ touch foobar foobak fooqux barbar boofar
$ echo foo*
foobar foobak fooqux
```

As you can see, the `*` expanded and listed the matching file names. (In this case, those that begin with `foo`.)

Now let's try another example:

```
$ touch gray.txt grey.txt
$ echo gr?y.txt
gray.txt grey.txt
```

`?` matches a single character. Nothing more. In this case, `gray.txt` and `grey.txt` both matched the pattern, so both were printed.

Another example:

```
$ touch hello hullo hallo
$ echo h[aeu]llo
hallo hello hullo
```

What happened here? As you know from before, `[aeu]` is a character class. A character class matches exactly one of the characters in it; it never matches more than one character. In this case, the characters in the character class could match the filenames correctly, so the results were printed out.

**If no matching file names are found, the word is left unchanged.**

### Explanation for your specific case

```
$ echo [s]
```

`[s]` is a character class and it matches just one character — a literal `s`. But no matching files were found, so it was returned as it is.

```
$ echo [t]
```

`[t]` is a character class as well. It matches one single character. There was a file named `t` in your directory, meaning there was a match. So it returned the name of the found file name.

```
$ echo [root]
```

`[root]` matches the following characters: `r`, `o`, `t`. As you probably guessed, `o` occurring twice in the character class doesn't make a difference here. A character class can only match a single character. So `echo [root]` will try to find filenames that has a matching character. Since a file named `t` exists in your directory, it is listed out.

### How to avoid such quirks?

**Always use quoting and escaping where needed.** They give you general control over parsing, expansion and expansion's results.

Answer (score 9):

To complement [devnull's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23140538/45375):

**Using an *unquoted* string in bash (in most cases) causes it to be interpreted as a *pattern*** (wildcard expression; loosely speaking, a distant, primitive relative of a regular expression).

In your case, the **pattern is matched against the names of files and subfolders in the current working folder**, as @devnull demonstrates: `[root]` means: match any file whose name consists of just 1 character that is *either* `r` *or* `o` (specifying `o` twice is redundant) *or* `t`.
This matching of a pattern against filenames is called **pathname expansion**.

Note that it **also applies to unquoted *variable* references**, so the following would yield the same result:

```
s='[t]'  # Assign string _literal_ (since quoted) to variable.
echo $s  # Content of $s, since unquoted, is now subject to pathname expansion.
```

To **treat a string (selectively) *literally*, you must use *quoting*.**

There are **three ways of quoting strings in `bash`**, using your example:

---

**`\`- quote individual characters** that have special meaning (so-called *metacharacters*):

`echo \[t\]`

This ensures that these otherwise special characters are treated as *literals*.

---

Enclose the string in **single quotes** (`'...'`):

`echo '[t]'`

This protects the string from *any* expansions (interpretation) by the shell.
**Caveat**: you cannot include a `'` itself in a single-quoted string (not even with escaping).

---

Enclose the string  in **double quotes** (`"..."`):

`echo "[t]"`

This protects the string from *some* expansions by the shell, while selectively allowing others.

In the case at hand, `'[t]'` and `"[t]"` behave identically.

However, **use of `"` allows you to *reference variables* (parameter expansion), perform *command substitutions*, and perform *calculations* (arithmetic expansion)** 
inside the string, e.g.:

`echo "Home, sweet $HOME." # reference to variable $HOME; parameter expansion`

`echo "Today's date and the current time are: $(date)" # command substitution`

`echo "Let's put $(( 2 + 2 )) together." # arithmetic expansion`

For a **list of all expansions** performed by `bash`, search for section `EXPANSION` in `man bash` or visit https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html.