# Bash Script: printing grep'd lines from file

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to grep lines matching some pattern and then trying to print those matched lines.

```
#!/bin/bash

file=/path/to/some/file
pattern=socket
if [ -f $file ]; then
    lines=`grep -i "$pattern" $file`
# Case 1
    for x in $lines; do   # <--- isn't this an array
        echo "$x"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        done
# Case 2
    while read -r line_a; do
        echo "$line_a"
        done <<< "$lines"
fi
```

**Output:**
Case 1: Instead of complete line, individual words from those lines are printed on each new line.
Case 2: Individual lines are printed.

**Question:**
Why doesn't case 1 print the whole line on one line instead of printing individual words from that line on each new line? Isn't `$lines` an array of strings (lines in my case) ?

Comment: No it is not an array, you capture the result of `grep` as one big string by using backticks. I am guessing the for loop is treating whitespace as the record separator and so each word is treated as an element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently capturing the output using back ticks which considers the entire output as one big string. If you want to capture it as an array use the following notation

```
lines=($(grep -i "$pattern" $file))
```

However, the default record separator is whitespace so each array element will be a single word and not an entire line from the `grep` output. You can circumvent this by (temporarily) changing the record separator `IFS` to split on new line characters. The whole solution would look like the following

```
IFS=$'\n'
lines=($(grep -i "$pattern" $file))
for x in ${lines[@]}; do
    echo $x
done
```

Note that you now have changed `IFS` for the shell and you would probably want to reset it to the old value. As you can see, this approach is very likely not the most optimal for your problem, but I posted it here to answer your original question

Comment: `lines=($(grep -i "$pattern" $file))`....It still doesn't work. It is storing white space separated characters as elements of the array.

Comment: are you setting the `IFS` to a newline character properly?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks!

Comment: If you don't double-quote `${lines[@]}`, it is subject to word splitting _again_ - while this does no harm in this case - given that `$IFS` is still set to a `\n` - it is unnecessary. More importantly, however, using `lines=($(grep -i "$pattern" $file))` will invariably subject the lines output by the `grep` command to pathname expansion (globbing), which is typically undesired.

Answer (score 3):

> Isn't $lines an array of strings (lines in my case)?

No; `$lines` is a *scalar* string variable that contains the *entire output* captured from command `grep -i "$pattern" $file` - in other words: a single string comprising potentially multiple lines.

> Why doesn't case 1 print the whole line on one line instead of printing individual words from that line on each new line?

Because you're referencing variable `$lines` *unquoted*, which means that it is subject to *word splitting* (among other so-called [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)).

Word splitting means that the input is split into tokens by whitespace (even across lines), and each token is passed separately to the `for` loop.

---

With a single input string, even if you set `$IFS` to $`'\n'`, there is no safe way to to iterate over its lines with `for`, because the lines are still subject to pathname expansion (globbing); i.e., if a line contains a substring that happens to be a valid glob (filename pattern, e.g., `*`), it will be expanded to the matching filenames.

Using an *array* of lines in a `for` loop does work, but requires that it be populated with *unmodified* input lines; using `lines=($(grep -i "$pattern" "$file"))` to populate the array is NOT an option, for the same reasons as stated above.

---

You have two choices, both of which use a [process substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) to capture the `grep` command's output:

(a) If you truly need to read all lines up front into memory, read them robustly into an array as follows:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -ra lines < <(grep -i "$pattern" "$file")
```

In bash 4+, you can use `readarray -t lines ...` instead.

Then process them in a `for` loop as follows:

```
 for line in "${lines[@]}"; do # double quotes prevent word splitting and globbing
    echo "$line"
 done
```

(b) Otherwise, use a `while` loop to directly read `grep`'s output line by line:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "$line"
done < <(grep -i "$pattern" "$file")
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I recently started working on bash, where can I learn about when to use -  single/double quotes, back ticks, curly braces, square braces, round braces etc.. ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23140961/45375 will give you a quick intro to quoting; [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) discusses all expansions (substitutions) that the shell performs. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide is a great Bash resource in general. Also, don't forget `man bash`, which contains all relevant info, but is dense and not easy to read.

Comment: can you please explain (b), what is the value IFS is being set to? I am able to read the lines separately but in those lines any appearance of character "n" is being replaced by a " " (space).

Comment: `IFS=` (followed by a space) means that IFS is set to the _empty string_, which _deactivates_ word splitting, meaning that each input line is read _unmodified, as a whole_ into `$line`.

Comment: I have no explanation for "n" being replaced by a space. You could create a new question with the code in question and more details.